# How to trigger network-manager autoconnect?

Tags: 16.04, network-manager, plasma

Let's say that network-manager is connected to specific Wi-Fi network. When I click "Disconnect" via GUI from it then it never connects back.

But when I close the laptop lid, then open it back (so that system suspends and resumes) then network-manager automatically connects to the Wi-Fi network it finds.

How do I trigger network-manager from console to automatically connect to the Wi-Fi network it finds without doing system suspend and resume?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
nmcli device set IFNAME autoconnect yes
```

is the command you're searching for. It enables autoconnect for the device with the `i`nter`f`ace `name` `IFNAME`, see e. g. `nmcli device` to get this name. If the device is currently not connected but finds a network it can connect to when you execute this command, it will instantly connect.

Comment: Is there a way to read the current state of this setting for a device?

Comment: @AndreKR Not that I found quickly – that’s a very good [new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)!

Comment: I found out that in my case this setting seems to have no effect at all. I had to set `connection.autoconnect ` in the *connection* properties to control whether my GSM connection is up or down on boot.

Comment: @AndreKR its `nmcli -f name,autoconnect con`

Answer (score 9):

`device` as suggested only works if the connection is existing/up.

If you want the setting to be permanent, you need to modify the connection config instead of the device config:

```
nmcli connection modify IFNAME connection.autoconnect yes|no
```

Comment: Note that "IFNAME" here is the connection Id, uuid or path, and not the interface name as with `nmcli device ...`.